# How do I sync all mail folders on my HTC Desire?

Tags: email, exchange, imap

The mail application only synchronizes the inbox, both for IMAP and Exchange accounts.

I auto-sort my mail into folders at the server and need to see all folders in the phone to not miss any e-mails.

Do I need a different mail-application to poll subfolders or what?

Comment: I have the same issue with Desire, but i Also have a X10i, and this is moxier, and this works just fine.... In moxier I can choose witch folder to sync, but on desires solution, I'm not able to do so....... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible with HTC Email application. This email app sync the "Inbox" folder automatically, but every other folder you have is not synced, the app gets all mail in the folder when you enter that folder to see what's inside.

You have the option to use [K9Mail](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/), a free e-mail client for Android which supposedly has support for push mail and sync of multiple folders.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the native mail application (I used it just long enough to know I needed more), but I can confirm that K9 Mail supports syncing of either all your folders or some set of folders that you've designated. Their mail "class" system is spelled out here: https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/wiki/WorkingWithClasses

Comment: I actually tried K9Mail, but it wouldn't connect to our exchange server (and/or my account), for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I use moxier mail, works much better and worth the money, it syncs all the exchange stuff and even provides access to the GAL for contact lookups, plus the widget can display the configured synced folders only. Good stuff. Plus you can continue to use the pattern unlock.

Answer (score 0):

If I open the Mail app, when connected to Exchange, I can then go to Menu > Folders and select a folder to view. It will the grab content from the folder allowing you to view it. If you have your settings configured for all mail then you should see emails in those other folders.

My settings for Mail are as follows under Settings > Send & Receive:

- Entire Mail
- HTML
- As items arrive (I have time set to an hour before and after my work schedule)
- All
- Smaller than 1 MB

In order for each individual setting, that is what I have.

Comment: The thing is that I want to be notified of new mail in a folder _without_ having view it manually with Menu > Folders. It gets boring pretty quick.

Comment: How would this be feasible? Your phone is checking the inbox where all email goes unless you have rules setup in Outlook to move emails, which I'm assuming is the case for you otherwise your new emails would only show up in the inbox. You phone doesn't know about these rules so it doesn't know there is a new email in a different folder. I guess it might be possible to write an app or for the Mail app to have extended functionality. But right now this isn't possible without either.

Answer (score -2):

Go to the email app select MENU then select MORE then SEND N RECEIVE select download options under download options SELECT (ALL)

Then go back n check the folders they should sync n you should see your emails.