# My Droid phone won't sync my email subfolders automatically

Tags: email

In order to read or even know I have emails in my Outlook subfolders, I have to open each subfolder individually and allow it to sync.  This is very time consuming.  Is there a way to set up the email so it auto synchs my subfolders?  I tried the select all option but it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sync all mail folders on my HTC Desire?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/how-do-i-sync-all-mail-folders-on-my-htc-desire)

Answer (score 1):

Auto-Syncing subfolders means additional network traffic, and eats more of your battery -- which is why it's not generally to recommend. But if you insist, for *selected* folders it might be sometimes useful. What you need for this is an email app supporting the sync of subfolders. One such app is [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9).

Speaking of "Outlook subfolders": Outlook is a client, not a server -- so it's hard to tell what you're using. Aforementioned *K-9* supports IMAP (recommended), POP3 (only if needed), and also Exchange (via WebDAV -- only for those who have no alternative, but that's my personal opinion). Guess one of them should cover your demands.